# Calling Servlet From GWT FormPanel

Tags: gwt, servlets

How can I Pass parameter from FormPanel of GWT to Servlet?

```
FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
formPanel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()
                + "ntPdfDownload?myParam=" + String.valueOf(document.getId())+ "&myValue="+ConstantName.IS_REQUIRED.toString()+"");
formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET);
formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
formPanel.submit();
```

This is what I have done.. But I am not able to get parameters at Servelt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `ENCODING_MULTIPART`. Your method has to be `POST`. This is generally required when you want to upload files to server.

I guess you are passing simple parameters to your servlet.So, It should work without  `formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);`.

Comment: Check whether servlet is getting called ?

Comment: yes it is getting called. But request.getParameter("myParam") gives null value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the method from GET to POST, make sure that in the servlet you're also implementing

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){...}
```

instead of just the doGet(...)

Comment: -1: for "If you have changed the method from GET to POST" Its mentioned in the post about using GET method.